# What is the diference between RVR and RVR with letter?

Tags: instrument-flight-rules, aeronautical-charts, jeppesen

There are at least two symbols for the RVR representation on Jeppesen charts.

But I can't seem to find the definition for those. By any chance would you guys care to explain what each one means?

[image: ![RVR]

Comment: Which airports has these symbols?

Comment: Did you copy these images from an airport diagram  and if so, which airport?

Comment: @Bruno: if you find the below answer satisfactory, please mark it as „accepted“.

Answer (score 2):

According to *Introduction to Jeppesen Navigation Charts* [(available at the Jeppesen Website)](https://ww2.jeppesen.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Introduction-to-Jeppesen-Navigation-Charts.pdf), or alternatively at `JeppView Software > Text > Airway Manual > Introduction > Chart Legend Information`:

RVR measurement equipment symbols are mentioned in:

1. Airport Planview

   [image]

   > 11 - When known, the location of RVR transmissiometers are shown with any applicable identifiers.

   This means that **the letters indicate identification of the equipment assigned by the local authority**. We can see examples of this:
2. In [this chart for ENGM (Oslo, Norway)](http://www.matraair.hu/charts/ENGM.pdf), you can see that the RVR equipment symbols are not labeled "R" or "L" for the respective runways or for their position along the runway (touchdown, mid-field, rollout):

   [image]
3. In [this chart for EDDH (Hamburg, Germany)](http://www.matraair.hu/charts/EDDH.pdf), you can see an instance of the labeled RVR equipment symbols:

   | RWY | touchdown | mid-field | rolllout |
   | --- | --- | --- | --- |
   | 23 | "A" | "B" | N/A |
   | 05 | "C" | N/A | N/A |
   | 33 | N/A | N/A | N/A |
   | 15 | "E" | "F" | "G" |

   [image]